# Java Project Error after changing database from MySQL to SQLite

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite, netbeans, jdbc

i am learning java
i have created simple (CRUD) java program utilizing mysql,its works fine

and i want to try switching to SQLite with the same database(i already converted mysql database to sqlite)
i am using this JDBC driver: https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc
But somehow,netbeans cannot complete running my program(despite there are no errors before)
i got many new errors on output bar:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBCException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at tes.MainForm.Tampil(MainForm.java:46)
at tes.MainForm.<init>(MainForm.java:85)
at tes.MainForm$4.run(MainForm.java:329)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)`
```

My **DBConnection class**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class DBConnection {   
Connection c = null;
Statement script;

public DBConnection(){
    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
 //  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   // c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://c:/asa.accdb");
 c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/titit2.db");
   // c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/titit","root","root");
    script = c.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    System.out.println("Koneksi Sukses");
    }catch(  SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex){
    System.err.print(ex);
    }
}
}
```

Inside my **mainform class** (line 23-46)

```
    private void Tampil(){
    try{
        int row = tabel.getRowCount();
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
            tabeldata.delete(0, row);
        }
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT * from asu";
            ResultSet rs = c.script.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()){
            DataPegawai d = new DataPegawai();
            d.setNo(rs.getInt("no"));
            d.setNip(rs.getInt("nip"));
            d.setNama(rs.getString("nama"));
            d.setDivisi(rs.getString("divisi"));
            d.setLevel(rs.getInt("level"));
            tabeldata.add(d);
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.print(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClassNotFoundException` is an exception you can get during runtime. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html where it says the possible cause:

> Thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its string name using:
>
> - The forName method in class Class.
> - The findSystemClass method in class ClassLoader .
> - The loadClass method in class ClassLoader.

So the problem is from my point of view, that you did not add it in netbeans to classpath correctly.

Moreover you should check you used the stable released version of driver. I'd suggest to use: [sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar)

Comment: Thank you,i think i got the wrong version
but i got new error:
`java.sql.SQLException: SQLite only supports TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY cursorsException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at tes.MainForm.Tampil(MainForm.java:31)
 at tes.MainForm.<init>(MainForm.java:52)
        etc..`

Comment: @Adamanusia please raise new question for this one. As this one sounds like fixed to me.